# Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, error-handling, wamp

I can see **Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value** problem at my WAMP server with mysql 5.7.19

I have enabled **sql-mode=""** at my.ini and restarted server but same problem.

Can anyone help me out?? How can I fix that??

Thanks

Comment: You should show the code that generates the error.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO user(username, password, role) VALUES('$username', '$password', '$role')";

I am skipping email field which is varchar Null as defualt

Comment: . . As the author of the question, can you edit it with more relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has very little information.  But, this typically happens when you are inserting into a table and explicitly list some of the columns:

```
insert into t(a, b, d)
    values (1, 2, 4);
```

If `c` is declared `NOT NULL` and doesn't have a default value, then you have an error.  The `insert` provides no data for the column and `NULL` is not an acceptable value.

Comment: I declared default value as null for c

Comment: Yes. You are right. I didn't assign null as default another row. Thanks a lot.